# Why does Sonny say they call Michael "Giogali"?

Tags: dialogue, the-godfather-2

In *The Godfather Part II*, Sonny introduces Michael to Carlo. He tells Carlo they call Mike "Giogali".

Who is "Giogali"?

Comment: Did you try turning on subtitles?  That's what I do when I can't clearly make out a line or word in dialog.  Usually the subs have something sensible that you can confirm once you have that interpretation of the sound in your mind.

Answer (score 32):

### You misheard

The actual quote is:

> We call him **Joe College.**

This is because Michael is the more educated brother and attended Dartmouth College before enlisting in the Marines. It's something of a put-down by Sonny as though Michael is *different* from the rest of the family.

[**An earlier version of the script**](https://www.awesomefilm.com/script/godfather2.html) (which had to be revised when Brando wasn't available) has a slightly different wording but the scene is essentially the same:

> ```
>   SONNY
>     Hey, who knows my buddy Carlo Rizzi.
>     Here... my brother Fredo, here's my
>     Mom.  Mom, whatcha got cooking?
>     And Carlo, this is my kid sister
>     Connie.  Here, pull up a chair,
>     Carol is sitting next to Connie.
>     Oh, the droopy kid over there is
>     Mike.  **The college boy.**
> ```

Comment: In 2 different data bases of movie scripts, one says, " Joe College", another says, "Joe Collars". But listen carefully to the dialogue (you can do this on YouTube). I read once of an Italian mathematician named Giogali. I can't find any more on him. Anyway, like I said, crank the volume and listen to what Sonny actually says. And thanks for responding.

Comment: I know the second source you are referring to and it;s occasionally useful but unreliable....the 1973 script has a slightly different version where Michael is referred to as "the college boy"...presumably this was changed in a later when they couldn't get Brando You can read the script here - https://www.awesomefilm.com/script/godfather2.html